# Ground loop between two devices powered by the same power supply

Tags: raspberry-pi, wireless, grounding, ground-loop

I'm working on a project with a Raspberry Pi and a Bluetooth receiver which are sharing the same ground and the same power supply.
The wireless receiver gets the signal (audio content) and sends it out to the RPi over its headphones output (the only audiuo output available at the moment).

the connection is unbalanced on a 3.5mm stero jack and enters into an ADC's audio input of the RPi.

When i reproduce the audio in the RPi, I can hear the very typical ground loop noise even though the grounding is only 1. 
As more as the RPi processor works, as more the noise increases.

The audio input in of the RPi touches the Device A's power ground because this reduces the noise quite a lot.

The noise goes away if i power the wireless receiver with a battery but i'm trying to get rid of the battery itself.

Is this a problem of ground loop that i can try to remove isolating the signals with a 1:1 transformer/ Ground break Circuit/ other...or is dued to other reasons?

[image: practicaldrawing]

Edit>
Audio of the noise (amplified!): https://v3.fastupload.co/file/8023

- picture of the connections

[image: Pic2]

plus follows the VCC on the oscilloscope.
if i remove the Wireless receiver from the connection, the ripples decrease[image]

Comment: Surely we can't tell exactly what the problem is, but you can try isolating it. Is the "green" line containing GND signal? If it does, then ground loop is very possible.

Comment: What is also very well possible is that the RPi loads the supply in such a way that there will be a lot of **noise** and **ripple** on supply lines (between VCC and Ground). If the receiver doesn't have very good power supply rejection/filtering that noise can end up in its output signal. I would disconnect the receiver's VCC (leave ground connection as-is) and power it from a battery. Does that solve it: then VCC is the issue. If not, also disconnect the ground connection so you break the ground loop.

Comment: If the green cable includes a ground, consider using that as the ONLY ground connection for the wireless RX.

Comment: Please show us a photo of the setup with all wiring visible.

Comment: Audio input in of the RPi is touchin the Device A power ground  because this reduces the noise of quite a lot. The noise goes away if i power the wireless receiver with a battery but i'm trying to get rid of the battery. Today i try to insert 0.1uf and 100uf capacitor before the receiver power input

Comment: @user_1818839 the devices are powered from the same source. How can i remove its power ground and having it still running?

Comment: What is this "typical ground loop noise" you're hearing?  What frequency?

Comment: Try filtering the power supplied to your receiver. Perhaps add a ferrite bead in series (as close to the receiver as possible) and a cap (or two, with different ESRs) between the power and ground (again, as close to the receiver as possible). You can also try adding the same type of components near the raspberry pi, as near as possible, although my guess is that the current requirements of Pi would require larger bead and cap values.

Comment: I don't think you have a ground loop problem, but rather a signal return problem.  We need to see exactly how the power and return runs are routed physically, not just from a block diagram standpoint.

Comment: updated. after finding a solution would get rid of the mess, of course.